Self-hosted PDF annotator for alpha and beta readers
Background
While writing a novel, I'd like to get feedback from alpha and beta readers. Currently, I build a PDF and send an email to each reader individually. A number of readers have requested the ability to send me feedback by adding annotations to the PDF directly. Ideally, without having to install any software on their laptop, desktop, or phone.
Workflow
In the following workflow diagram, the upper half is already accomplished using a shell script to upload and email a hyperlink to an alpha reader:

The lower half is the problem to be solved.
Requirements

Must integrate with existing web server.
Must use PHP for handling server-side requests.
Must have a zero authentication mode (the links are private).
May not use cloud or SaaS.
Should integrate with .htaccess files.
Should use a flat file system (preferably no database).

.htaccess
An .htaccess file can be used to invoke PHP to intercept and annotate the PDF before sending back to the browser:
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Ensure the file exists before attempting to download it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

# Inject annotations based on contents from filename.yaml.
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.pdf)$ update.php?filename=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

This way of intercepting the PDF allows users to receive a simple hyperlink without seeing special query parameters.
JavaScript
For client-side editing the following seem feasible:

pdf.js
pdf-lib

Having the client-side code send annotation edits to the server via AJAX would be ideal. For example:
HTTP PUT https://hostname/alpha/filename.pdf?page=2&x=42&y=50&type=note&text="feedback"

Question
Do you know of any super-simple solution that can allow users to edit PDF files, having their changes stored server-side?
